# how do i echo a link in php that contains php with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

so i am trying to echo a link to to call a function to load a view in CodeIgniter. this is the link:

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/signup" ?>'>Sign Up!</a>

echo '<a href=\'<?php echo base_url()."main/login" ?>\'>Log In!</a>';
```

i am running an Acer Aspire 5920,

Ubuntu 12.04,

Xampp 1.8.1,

Codeigniter 2.1.3

Comment: Fine. And your question is?

Comment: i asked it. that wont echo the php wont run

Comment: ie the php in side the link

Comment: i already tried simply using an \ before each ' but that didnt work

Comment: Sorry, but you never mentioned it does not work... or _what_ does not work. You took a look at the log files? I assume there is a parse error, maybe the function base_url() does not exist?

Comment: it is a codeigniter function and i use it with out problem on other pages, just by using straight html outside of php tags. when i echo it  with \ before each ' the php tags in side the html href tag get spit out instead of ran

Comment: So what do the log files contain?

Comment: Maybe if you could add the result in HTML?

Comment: there is no record of any error in the log when i run the code. if i run it with \ before ' i get this in the address bar: https://localhost/main/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url().%22main/login%22%20?%3E  and this in the browser Disallowed Key Characters.

Comment: the code only gets shown if the are not logged in, i check it with an if statement

Comment: Sorry, but with the second line of code you added to your question you really confuse different php strategies. When the whole code is running inside php, then why do you add additional control seuquences (`<?php` and `?>`) ? That cannot work.

Comment: Post the whole code, not just a single line. This is fruitless otherwise.

Comment: u got the answer for me arkascha, i wasnt thinking could have just concatenated all of it, its fixed and works now, thank you

Comment: the answer was simple once it clicked in my mind

Comment: Fine! One more thing: when trying to solve stuff like that, always check the html markup source code inside the browser. Something like CTRL-U or 'View Source'. You would have seen what is actually contained inside the href attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the php tags from between the href, something like this:

```
echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'main/login'">Log In!</a>';
```

Good luck!